# Adding Views to Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Let's say I have an `Activity` that consists of a `View`/`ViewGroup` with a `Button` that takes up 100% of the space. Now, by pressing the `Button`, I would like to add a `View`/`ViewGroup` so that both items take up 50% of the screen (and so on). I thought I could do it with the `FragmentTransactions` (because then I might also eventually learn how to make the effect of adding the new Views look good) and so `FrameLayout` and then adding `Fragments` was the solution, but apparently you can only add one `Fragment` per `FrameLayout`?

**Edit:** This is what I have so far. Keep in mind that this is only an example, I do want to add more complex Views eventually (to account for layout changes):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragTrans.add(R.id.Frame1, new AddFragFrag());
        fragTrans.commit();
    }
```

}

**activity_main.xml:** (in a vertically oriented LinearLayout)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Frame1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Frame2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**AddFragFrag.java**

```
public class AddFragFrag extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addfragfrag, container, false);

        Button addFragButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addFragmentButton);
        addFragButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("addFragFrag.java", "Adding new Fragment...");
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.add(R.id.Frame2, new But2());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

**addfragfrag.xml** (also within a LinearLayout)

```
<Button android:id="@+id/addFragmentButton"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add Button Fragment"/>

<!--  more stuff here later -->
```

Here to visualize what I would like:

```
------------------
| -------------- |
| |            | |
| |            | |
| |            | |
| | ViewGroup1 | |
| |            | |
| |            | |
| |            | |
| |            | |
| -------------- |
------------------

       ==>  (by pressing a button, layout, event, ...)

------------------
| -------------- |
| |            | |
| | ViewGroup1 | |
| |            | |
| -------------- |
| -------------- |
| |            | |
| | ViewGroup2 | |
| |            | |
| -------------- |
------------------
```

Comment: If you're interested in animating views, you might like the [APIs added in KitKat](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Animations). There is also a [backport] for ICS+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got it! It turns out there were many aspects to this problem that I had not grasped yet (and probably still don't fully understand).

One issue was that I could not get the Views/ViewGroups to got from 100% to 50% (or vice versa). This can be resolved by setting the Visibility to either GONE or VISIBLE, like so:

```
FrameLayout hideFL = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Frame1);
hideFL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The second issue was that I couldn't properly reference the various Views/ViewGroups (e.g. by using *findViewById(...)* ), especially if they were inflated by the Fragment. And while I'm still a bit confused by the Activity's *onCreate(...)* and the Fragment's *onCreateView(...)*,  I did realize that *onCreateView* comes after *onCreate* and I can address the Views/ViewGroups once they are fully "loaded". So I moved the code that manipulates those to the *onStart()* method. I'm not sure if this is the recommended approach, but it certainly helped on a lot of my problems I was having.

Last but not least there was also the problem of having the code for the second Button in the Fragment (_AddFragFrag.java). It turns out you are not supposed to do that, so I deleted that part entirely. Obviously you are supposed to implement an interface, and I found a good tutorial for that here:
[Using Fragments in Android - A Worked Example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example#Making_the_Toolbar_Fragment_Talk_to_the_Activity)

So here is the modified code which does what I wanted in the first place (*note that this also works when adding Fragments to something other than FrameLayouts, which was another problem that I was having*):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AddFragFrag.OnButtonClickedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout hideFL = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Frame1);
        hideFL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Button addFragButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addFragmentButton);
        addFragButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("addFragFrag.java", "Adding new Fragment...");
            FrameLayout remFL = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Frame1);
            remFL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.add(R.id.Frame1, new AddFragFrag());
            fragTrans.commit();
        }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick(String s)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked a button! Yeah!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml** (again, inside a LinearLayout)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addFragmentButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Add 2nd Button" 
/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Frame1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a simple `Button`, you don't need to implement a whole `Fragment` for that, also, you can add only one fragment to a `FrameLayout` (as far as I know)

so to add you buttons and to give all of them the same space, you have to set the `weight` of each one to `1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinearLayout and give each button equal weight.